# Is making market research for gambling companies haram?

Tags: halal-haram, gambling

Assalam aleykum,
I started working last week for a company that does market research for all types of businesses. This company I work for has main clients in the gambling industry. I am employed as programmer to build the online market research surveys used to get market info from the public which my company then uses to consult the client on how to do better business.
Is it haram for me to work with such projects?

If the company refuses and says that I have to work with all projects including the gambling project is it haram for me to stay with the company?

Appreciate your answers. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Is making market research for gambling companies haram?

As a semi-direct/related answer: to the best of my knowledge, working/helping in the related jobs of gambling is haram, and its income will be haram, too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is Haram. It's the fourteenth greatest sin to do gambling.

In Qur'an,

> “They ask you about intoxicants and games of chances. Say: in both of them there is a great sin...”(Surah al-Baqarah 2:219)

and

> “O you who believe! Intoxicants and (Maesir) games of chance and divining (azlam) by arrows are only an uncleanness, the Shaitan’s work; shun it therefore that you may be successful.” (Surah al-Mā’ida 5:90)

In Hadith,

> “Whoever calls people to guidance will have a reward like that of those who follow him, without that detracting from their reward in the slightest, and whoever calls people to misguidance will have a burden of sin like that of those who follow him, without that detracting from their burden of sin in the slightest.”

So by doing that you are helping people to gamble. So let's consider stopping it which is much better and riskless for you.

Comment: Jazzak Allah kheir. May Allah SWT grant me, you and all muslims the best and hallal rizq and give us success and prosperity in it.